# Is there a way to check out a file under a different username using tfs powershell snapin?

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfvc

I'd like to checkout a file under a different username using powershell's tfs snapin.  Except, I don't see a login or user switch when I lookup `Add-TfsPendingChange`.

Is there a way of doing this?

I'd rather not switch between the snapin and the cmd line versions if possible.  Shouldn't need to do that anyway.

Comment: There's always the option of using `Invoke-Command` with the `-Credential` argument to run the command under different credentials.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, how would that work?  I don't think that the tfs username is on the domain.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Our TFS servers run off our domain accounts. I wasn't aware that they ran other ways. You should still be able to build a credential object that isn't a domain account but just providing it the user name and password though.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, the account is a build account.  I don't think that it's on the domain.  Could be wrong though.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, Could you give an example on how I would use it?  Thanks,

Comment: You can see an example of creating a PSCredential object [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/koteshb/archive/2010/02/13/powershell-creating-a-pscredential-object.aspx).

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, I still don't see how I can use this object.  I don't see a parameter that take a `System.Management.Automation.PSCredential` object.  It doesn't take a `-PSCredential` parameter.

Comment: As noted in my first comment, you would use it with the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet, which *does* have the `-Credential` parameter.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, ah, well just tried that and it doesn't seem to work.  Here's my cmd:  `Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -Credential '' -ScriptBlock { Add-TfsPendingChange  -Edit .\DEV.sln }` and with domain credentials it states: `[localhost] Connecting to remote server localhost failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see 
the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.`, using the local computer's user/pass, it partially works, in that it logs in, but that is not on the domain, so the tfs command doesn't do anything.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, my actual command is:  `Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -Credential '' -ScriptBlock { add-pssnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell; Add-TfsPendingChange  -Edit .\DEV.sln }` but I ran out of room.

Comment: exclude the `-Computer` parameter. Also, your `-Credential` parameter is not valid.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, Can't exclude the `-Computer` switch.  I get the error: `Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.`  Also, the `-Credential` parameter stated like that will prompt for credentials.  If I specify them, it does the same thing.  FYI, the computer I'm doing this on is **NOT** on the domain.

Comment: I stand corrected. I haven't seen the `-Credential` parameter used that way before, but I am most definitely not infallible. It looks like you would need to enable remote sessions so that `Invoke-Command` can run the command under different credentials on your machine. Honestly, for your configuration this may be more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, I'm not sure what you mean by enable remote sessions.  I've enabled it on the computer that I'm trying this on.  Before I did that, I got a bunch of different errors.

Answer (score 0):

TFS power-shell snapin use the credential which is entered when create the workspace and only provide basic version control commands feature. Call "tf.exe" in powershell script directly would be an easy way to achieve the feature you want. If you don't like this method, you can involve TFS API in your powershell script. Refer to "Beyond the basics" in this link for details: [PowerShell and TFS: The Basics and Beyond](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/04/21/powershell-and-tfs-the-basics-and-beyond/).

Comment: Yeah, I have tried this.  When I enter the command `Add-Type –AssemblyName "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"`, I get a `CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.TeamF...03f5f7f11d50a3a:String) [Add-Type], Exception` and `FullyQualifiedErrorId : ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand` error.

Comment: @Adrian Do you have VS and Team Explorer installed on the PC and what is the version? You are trying to import a version of 2012 which seems does not exist on your PC. The version 11 equals to 2012, 12 equals to 2013 and 14 equals to 2015.

Comment: Ah, that would explain it.  The version was wrong.  As for the article you referenced, yeah, the "Beyond" part isn't very useful.  Yes, it states how to connect to the .NET classes, but beyond that there is nothing.  This is more complicated than it really needs to be. :(